# Hashtable values displayed in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hashtable

[image]I am debugging a Hashtable in Eclipse and found something strange. My Hashtable variable name is "my_hashTable", and Eclipse debugger, if I　click it, it shows its values are three: {first=0, third=2, second=1}, which is correct as expected, and the count is 3, which is correct too.

However, if I　click the "table" variable inside the my_hashTable variable, it shows there are only two non-null values, [4] = 2 and [5] = 0. Its full values are below:

[null, null, null, null, third=2, first=0, null]

Why does this happen? Where is the "second=1" pair? This is the first time I encountered this odd observation in Eclipse.

Any idea of what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: nice question. can you post up some pictures too?

Comment: I want to attach a snapshot, but SOF doesn't allow me to do that?

Comment: it is impossible.you can add pictures if you want to

Comment: Are you seeing the inconsistency?

Comment: In the picture, my_hashtable shows it has 3 values, while "table" shows it only has values in index 4 & 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61309/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-martin).

Comment: can't reproduce your bug. what eclipse are you using?

Comment: and it's strange because it shows from index 4. Usually it would show you from index 0, even if 0,1,2,3 were all nulls

Comment: @martin Just expand your table array and search for the next,which points to the next Map.Entry table.You would get your Map.Entry Object.This is how Hash based collections work.Look at my answer

Comment: Thats because of the hash collision (when it tries to % by length of the array)

Comment: @Leo This is how Hash based collections work.They don't fill buckets of table serially but rather on the basis of Object hashcode() using the underlying hashing algorithm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above situation arises because of `HashTable` structure where table array stores the key-value pairs in the form of `Map$Entry`.**If two keys hash to the same bucket** using the  `Object hashcode() and the underlying Collection's hashing algorithm`,they would be put in the same bucket(say table[j] )in the form of a **singly-linked list using the next reference present in each Map$Entry Object**.Thus.each table index contains a `Map$Entry`Object with a reference to **next** `Map$Entry`Object having the same hashbucket(but whose keys are **unequal** as per the `equals()` method of the Key Object).The thing is that the keys would be unequal as per the equals() method of the Key but their bucket index would be same `using the hashcode() and hashing algorithm applied.`

Just expand any of your visible table indexes for the next,and you would find the Key-value pair in the form of `Map$Entry`.

Each **Map$Entry** stored in table array has the following structure:-

```
1)key 
2)value
3)hashcode
4)next -contains reference of next Map$Entry
```

This is how Hash based collections work.Objects whose hashing algorithm return the same index are stored in the same bucket(table index) as a singular linked List.

Comment: +1 Good one, `int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;` this is what happens when we call put on hashtable.

Comment: @Rp Thanks.I would also like to point out that if there was no resizing method() in HashTable(or HashMap) and I had declared a HashMap of initial size 1,then adding of elements would always show a single bucket. :) ..

Comment: Yes, I found it. "Third" and "Second" are in the same list. So two strings "third" and "second" can be potentially hashed to the same index?

Comment: @martin Of course,but they are differentiated using their equals method.This is why it is essential that Hash Based collections use an Object as key which have good hashing algorithm.they should prefereably return different hashcodes for different Objects

Comment: Does this mean a better hashing algorithm should be used in this example? In fact, the hashtable stores a String -> Integer pairs, and the hashing should have been provided by Java as default. Can it be even better?

Comment: @Martin.Just having 2 elements in a single bucket will hardly affect your performance for basic operations such as get(Object) or containsKey(Object).As soon as your table size reaches a threshold,it would rehash the entire table contents to a new HashTable where the elements would be distributed in an even better way.

Comment: @martin Alternativly,you can keep the initial size of HashTable slightly higher so that Objects gets hashed to different locations.But note that this will lead to memory tradeoff.Thus,you have to set the HashTable's initial size  so that your Objects get hashed to different locations without being significant loss in memory

Comment: @Rp-I guess that there is memory tadeoff but we can reasonably expect to hash different Objects in different buckets by keeping the initial size high?int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length; Higher tab.length should do the trick